# Tektro HD-R210 bleed port adapter identification

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

I have a generic brake bleed kit and I'd like to use it on my Tektro HD-R210. I'm pretty sure the brakes are just an OEM version of the Tektro HD-R310 - when I asked Tektro for support with the HD-R210 they referred me to the documentation of the HD-R310.

The instructions in the kit aren't too clear and don't seem to match the contents of the kit.

There was a bag containing 10 brass fittings labelled 1-10 in the photo, as well as a separate bag with the two fittings labelled 11-12 along with plastic fittings, some clear tubing, and clamps.

Can someone help identify which adapters are compatible with the HD-R210 bleed ports?

The kit is labelled EZmtb master version.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard back from Tektro USA

> It’s going to be an m6 thread pitch and is probably 4,11 or 12

I tested the parts and 2, 4, 11, 12 and 9 are m6 threaded parts. These parts mated properly with the bleed port on the brake lever.

The male threaded ends of 1 and 6 are compatible with the female end of 9.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's possible someone might randomly know, but for the most part that's not how this game works.

Bleed fitting typology on random OEM type hydros is chaos. There are no resources. It's not all the same within brands. It's figured out by having a variety of options when you crack it open.

When you take out the bleed screw, look at the diameter, pitch, threaded length, presence or absence of an o-ring, and shoulder profile. All you're trying to do is find a fitting that's a match. Usually in a nice completist set like this, something is going to match exactly. Assuming you're doing a two-syringe bleed, where you skloosh the fluid back and forth until no more bubbles come out, you'll do the same for the lever end. (This method works best for most Tektro brakes in my experience despite how their basic consumer bleed kit only comes with one syringe.)

Some Tektro caliper fittings don't have an o-ring and may not seal right if the syringe fitting you attempt to use has an o-ring. So if you run into sealing problems, remember you can take the o-ring off a fitting you have to create a match.

If by some chance you open a bleed port and find you don't have a match, it's true that's not ideal and it's theoretically possible to introduce air and find yourself in worse shape then when you started, but in practical terms the other end being sealed is going to keep the bulk of the fluid in, so all you're likely to lose is some droplets right at the opening. You can carefully drip a little oil back in and seal it up and there shouldn't be much change if any.

Take heart that the ironic thing about bleeding Tektros is that despite lack of clear written procedure, it almost always works out fine if you just do it. Over the years I've come to postulate that that's why the written procedures are so bad; they seem like an afterthought because they probably are.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. So is this going to be a matter of trial and error? My concern with proceeding that way is that I might damage the thread on the ports.

Comment: @Scottmeup You need to have enough understanding of threaded fastener concepts to avoid that. But in practical terms, if you take out the bleed port screw and interlock the threads with the prospective fitting and see no light gap, and the diameters are the same, it's fine. Google around and you'll see illustrations of this. Threaded bleed ports are mostly or all standard M5 or M6 threads. All of this is probably irrelevant though because as soon as you pull the screw, you're probably going to find one of your fittings is clearly identical to it or very close, which is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just try all the fittings that seem like a match. Just be careful not to force anything, the right fitting will thread on without effort. Go for a funnel bleed, or even better a gravity bleed. Using two syringes is unnecessary effort.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the answers you need. I'm going to add for completeness that (especially the rear brake on) most Tektro hydraulics I've encountered, they feel like they need bleeding when the pads are worn past a certain point. Resetting the calipers and replacing the pads solves the problem, where resetting the calipers, bleeding properly and reusing the old pads puts you back where you were before you started.

They are still good brakes for the money.